# Showing progressiveness for functions underlying an SDE.

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Laying the groundwork to study SDEs we discussed the following:

We consider the SDE $dX_t = f(t,X) dB_t$ where $f: \mathbb{R}_+ \times C(\mathbb{R}_+,\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$. This means that we consider the entire sample path of $X$ in the SDE. Because we still only want dependence up to a time $t$, we define a filtration on $C(\mathbb{R}_+,\mathbb{R})$, namely
$$
\mathcal{G}_t := \sigma(\pi_s:s \in [0,t]),
$$
where $\pi_s$ maps a continuous function $w$ to $w(s)$ (evaluation map).

Using this definition we can consider $\mathbb{G}$-progressive maps $f$. We say that $f$ is $\mathbb{G}$-progressive, if for all $t \geq 0$, we have that
$$
f: [0,t] \times C(\mathbb{R}_+,\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}
$$
is $\mathcal{B}([0,t]) \otimes \mathcal{G}_t$ measurable.

We showed that, whenever X is an adapted and continuous process, then the map $\mathbb{R}_+ \times \Omega \ni (t,\omega) \mapsto f(t, X(\omega))$ is progressive in the usual sense.

**Question:** Now I wanted to show that the usual dependence on "only" $X_t$ is also progressive, i.e. show that for a continuous and adapted process $X$, the map $\mathbb{R}_+ \times \Omega \ni (t,\omega) \mapsto f(t, X_t(\omega))$ is progressive in the usual sense, when $f$ is $\mathbb{G}$-progressive.

Can someone give me a hint on how to proceed? Usually there is a clever decomposition of the map, but I can't seem to find it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $f:[0,t]\times C\to \mathbb{R}$, what are you indicating with $f(t,X_t(\omega))$? The latter seems to me to be $[0,t]\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes, it seems like $[0,t] \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. However, if $f$ as a function from $[0,t] \times C$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{G}$-progressive, and I want to use this fact, I can also think of $X_t(\omega)$ as a (constant) continuous function, right?

The question is, whether this is useful, or leads to what I want. Maybe, I have to look at it as a function from $[0,t] \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, but how does this help me, or relate to the fact that $f$ is $\mathbb{G}$-progressive?